Как обновлять геообъект в ymaps без перезагрузки страницы
Как сделать, чтобы в зависимости от переменной pt обновлялось значение present в placemark(оно не работает с этим кодом) и метка обновляла цвет без перезагрузки страницы?
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ymaps from 'ymaps';

function MapComponent() {

  const [variable, setVariable] = useState('');

      useEffect(() => {
        fetch('variable.txt')
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(data => setVariable(data));
      }, []);

  const [pt, setPt] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (variable <= 0) {
      setPt('islands#greenCircleDotIcon')
    } else if (variable > 0 && variable <= 60) {
      setPt('islands#yellowCircleDotIcon')
    } else if (variable > 60) {
      setPt('islands#redCircleDotIcon')
    }
  }, [variable]);

  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ymaps.load().then((ymaps) => {
      const map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.160682, 61.299485],
        zoom: 10,
      });

      setMap(map);

      const placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.160682, 61.299485], null, {
        preset: pt
      });

      map.geoObjects.add(placemark);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="map" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MapComponent;


Так ведь системе нужно знать, у какого placemark менять. А собственно менять preset просто:
placemark.options.set('preset',newPt);

